# I have several security issues with W10 Pre-Installed on my new HP Lap..is Skype {which keeps appearing everytime I log in} a MS App Now?

Tags: windows-10

I don't appreciate my time being wasted when I don't use Skype and I would just LOVE to remove it completely...but I need some advice here on how to do that.

Comment: What have you tried? Uninstalling programs hasn't really changed, even for the new Apps.

Comment: Well I did not know what to do...2 ans. so far have really helped...Skype tries to get loaded several times per session and believe me it is annoying so I will try what has been recommended to me here in this forum; As to the final outcome on this issue, I will update Ya'll ASAP! TIA

Answer (score -1):

Yes, microsoft owns skype now. You should be able to uninstall/deactivate it in Add/remove applications window or disable the autostart in msconfig.

Answer (score -1):

There is Desktop Skype (lives in Programs and Features and can be easily uninstalled. Windows 10 Skype - make sure you do not log into it and ignore it. Done like that, it does not start on my Windows 10 machine

Comment: great ans. John & many thanks -I will try this advice ASAP and post update for all interested...now with direction from ya'll I certainly feel welcome here as I could never get a straight ans. about anything on OS2world!